# TikZ 3.0.0 and Hobby

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

Compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[step=0.25] (1,1);
\draw[very thick,red!85!black] 
(0,0)
to[curve through={(0.15,0.35) .. 
                  (0.5,0.5)   .. 
                  (0.8,0.6)
                  }
  ]  
(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with TikZ version 3.0.0 gives:

[image]

The same MWE, with TikZ 2.10 leads to something *more expected*:

[image]

Why this difference?

Comment: Since TikZ 3.0 is not generally available, this question is on the verge of being off topic. It's quite clear that version 3 broke the working of `hobby`. `:(`

Comment: From the `in` and `out` angles, I think ThreekZ has an additional angle setting after `hobby` computes the angles. Can you try with explicit angles for in and out? And use units just to be safe in the troubleshooting :P

Comment: @egreg: perhaps the _why_ is too generic. Two ideas came in my mind (one concerning the parser, the second one about computations), but they could be completely wrong. Hence, behind the _why_ there's also an implicit _where_ besides a hopefully _how_ to solve it. Indeed according to _where_ are the causes, they may affect or not other packages. However, I think the question is on topic; for two reasons: according to [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/discussion/477362/thread/340b50b1/?limit=50#99f5) the new version _should have been_ already on CTAN. [next]

Comment: Second, we had in the past some questions on packages not generally available (pgfpie for example).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I didn't know that and heard instead that a couple of months were expected. I didn't vote for closing either, it was a way for asking you to improve the question.

Comment: @egreg: sure, I realized it was kind of vague `:)`. I will probably do it tomorrow, meanwhile I hope the comments will prevent to pile up close votes `;)` (at least I won't vote this time).

Comment: @percusse: it seems your intuition goes in the right direction; of course for computations I will try to avoid that path (not that I'm not able to compute those angles, of course `;)` ).

Comment: I will always vote for reopening this question, if it is closed!

Comment: @HenriMenke: nice people makes this a nice place `:)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Works for me:

[image: Hobby with TikZ3.0]

---

A major change from TikZ2.10 to TikZ3.0 is that they've reimplemented the `atan2` function *correctly*.  In old TikZ, the arguments were the wrong way around.  Putting the arguments in incorrectly leads to the behaviour that you see.

The version of hobby on [TeX-SX launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) fixes this in two ways:

1. The core hobby algorithm now uses the version of atan2 from `l3fp`.
2. The quick algorithm (which is implemented in PGF) uses PGF's atan2 but includes a test to see which version of the atan2 function is present and chooses its arguments accordingly.

(I'm pretty sure that this change was in response to a question on this site but I can't find it now.)

Now that TikZ3.0 is released, I should push this change to CTAN.  But I need to update the documentation and do a bit more testing first.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: I've just uploaded this version to CTAN.  Should propagate through in a day or so.